# How to use useState hook with formik

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, formik

I am making an authentication page following a tutorial but they create an array for useState, How do set or use this inside my formik form onChange like this they did.

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
const [loginUser, { data, isError, error }] = useLoginUserMutation()


useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.access_token) {
      localStorage.setItem(
        'login',
        JSON.stringify({
          userLogin: true,
          token: data.access_token
        })
      )
      setErrorMsg('')
      setEmail('')
      setPassword('');
      navigate('/about')
    }
    if (isError) {
      setErrorMsg(error.data.message)
    }
  }, [data, isError, error])

    const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    await loginUser({ email, password })
  }
```

2. The form can't read the input value when I put the onChange statement inside this formik, I get  email and password is required. It is supposed to read the value and onSubmit navigate to another page used inside the useEffect.

   ```
          <Formik
        initialValues={{
          email: '',
          password: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={validate}
        onSubmit={handleLogin}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting }) => (
          <Form className='py-4'>
            <div>
              <TextField
                label='Email Address'
                name='email'
                type='email'
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                placeholder='mail@company.com'
              />
            </div>

            <div className='relative'>
              <TextField
                label='Password'
                name='password'
                type={passwordShown ? 'text' : 'password'}
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                placeholder='******'

              />
              <i
                className='fa-solid fa-eye absolute top-[50px] right-4 cursor-pointer'
                onClick={togglePasswordVisiblity}
              ></i>
            </div>

            <div className='remember flex justify-between justify-items-center my-4'>
              <div className='check gap-2 flow-root'>
                <input type='checkbox' name='rememberMe' id='remeberMe' />{' '}
                Remember me
              </div>
              <Link
                to='/ForgetPassword'
                className='underline hover:underline hover:text-black'
              >
                {' '}
                Forget your password{' '}
              </Link>
            </div>

            <button
              type='submit'
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              className='border-0 py-2
              rounded hover:bg-[#0559FD]
              w-full bg-[#AAAAAA] text-white'
            >
              {' '}
              Log in{' '}
            </button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has to do with this fragment of code executed in `useEffect`:

```
setErrorMsg('')
setEmail('')
setPassword('');
```

Let me explain what is happening here step by step:

1. After each value change i.e. in `email` input, you are calling `setEmail` with the new value.
2. After the state is changed, component gets rerendered,
3. When the component gets rerendered, since `data && data.access_token` statement resolves to true, `setEmail('')` gets executed

How can you make sure I am right?

Put simple `console.log('calling!')` inside `if` statement of `useEffect`, then change the value of email input - verify if `console.log()` gets called every time after you change the value.

How can you fix this?

One of the solutions can be moving the code responsible of resetting inputs values to `onSubmit` function.